# Select and Deselect not working in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown `<select>` element to select states from the list of 50 states, I select the 1st value, save it, and show the value in DOM.  I changed and select to the 5th value, saving it shows the value updates in DOM. Now back i am selecting the 2nd Value, and saving it.  It's not saving the value in DOM and it's showing the previous selected 5th value. I Checked with different values, and found that, after selecting any higher index value, selecting back, lower values are not affecting in DOM, and hence i am not getting the correct values in POST.

This is the function i am calling on `change`.

```
function updateDOM(inputField) {
    var elementId = inputField;
    if (inputField.type == "select-one") {
       var prev_select = inputField.selectedIndex;
       $('#'+inputField.id+' option').each(
          function() {
             $(this).removeAttr('selected');
          }
       );
       document.getElementById(elementId.id).selectedIndex = prev_select;
       if (browserVersion == 9) {
          document.getElementById(elementId.id)
             .options[prev_select].setAttribute("selected","selected");
       }
       else {
          document.getElementById(elementId.id)
             .options[prev_select].setAttribute("selected","selected");
       }
       document.getElementById(elementId.id).value
          = document.getElementById(elementId.id).options[prev_select].value;
}
```

The HTML

```
   <select id="abc"  name="abc"  onchange="javascript:updateDOM(this);" class="required" >
      <option name="" value="" title="null" selected ></option>
      <option name="AK" value="Alaska" title="null"  >Alaska</option>
      <option name="AL" value="Alabama" title="null"  >Alabama</option>
      <option name="AR" value="Arkansas" title="null"  >Arkansas</option>
      <option name="AZ" value="Arizona" title="null"  >Arizona</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Why do you keep writing `document.getElementById(elementId.id)` instead of just `elementId`?

Comment: @Blazemonger, because `document.getElementById(elementId.id)` gets the actual node and `elementId.id` is just the string id.

Comment: If `inputField` is a DOM element, you're wasting your time. If it isn't, then you should cache `document.getElementById(elementId.id)` as a new variable early in your code, if for no other reason than to improve readability.

Comment: Either way, it would help us if you added the relevant HTML to your question.

Comment: Is there any reason to make such a hardcore mix of jQuery and vanilla code? :)

Comment: I see no purpose in you `updateDOM` function. All it does is get the selected index and select that option, which is already selected. pointless.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, not knowing what you're copying and pasting

Comment: @zgood: :). Code guidelines: google for something alike, copy'n'paste, post on SO for someone to make it run, ..., profit.

Comment: @zgood My objective is to show the preview of the form before submitting, so i was showing it using inner html, but there was error in updating the DOM showing some old values for radio buttons and all, so i wrote this UpdateDOM to change...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you use ":selected" selector of jQuery, which you are using anyway? Also, why are you using jQuery only once?
I would recommend doing it in jQuery-style (sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do exactly in your code):

http://jsfiddle.net/msLXt/1/

P.S. What is the difference between these conditions?

```
   if (browserVersion == 9) {
      document.getElementById(elementId.id)
         .options[prev_select].setAttribute("selected","selected");
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById(elementId.id)
         .options[prev_select].setAttribute("selected","selected");
   }
```